# jquery add class to all siblings except 1

Tags: jquery

I've got a list like this:

```
<ul id="items"><li><a href="">Link</a></li><li><a href="">Link</a></li><li class="divider"></li><li><a href="">Link</a></li><li><a href="">Link</a></li></ul>
```

When I click any of the anchors I want to add a class to all the li's except for the parent of the link that I clicked and the li with the "divider" class.

I can get it to work with all the siblings with this:

```
 $(this).parent().siblings().attr("class", "transparent");
```

So how do I get it to ignore the li with the "divider" class?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also use the [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) command to filter out anything from a set that you don't want. This is an alternative to passing in a CSS `:not` pseudo class selector as mentioned by Matt.

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not(".divider").addClass("transparent");
```

Also it's probably better to use [`.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

**Edit:**

jQuery is bad, use DOM ;)

```
link.addEventListener("click", function addClasses() {
    var li = this.parentNode,
        lis = li.parentNode.children;

    [].forEach.call(lis, function addClassIfCorrect(el) {
        var classList = el.classList
        if (el !== li && !classList.contains("divider")) {
            classList.add("transparent");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: jquery recommends using the .not() method.

Comment: @Kalinga It works on all modern browsers apart from IE. It can be shimmed using a DOM shim

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the `divider` class in your call to `siblings`:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(':not(.divider)').attr("class", "transparent");
```